# MySQL : How to count the position of the results in a Select?

Tags: mysql, count, ranking

I need to count the position of the results in a Select - like a RANKING.

I have this:

```
"SELECT PLAYERID, SUM(POINTS) AS POINTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY PLAYERID ORDER BY POINTS"
```

And I Get this:

```
PLAYERID   POINTS
4          200
2          150
1          100
3           80
```

I need to know the position in the Ranking for PlayerID = 1.

I'm not an expert in MySQL - but it's possible to count the results like this:

```
RK   PLAYERID   POINTS
1     4         200
2     2         150
3     1         100
4     3          80
```

Something like: "SELECT COUNT..."

tks a lot!
Daniel

EDIT: It's not duplicated because I don't want to create a ranking. I want to count the position of the result. The answer proposed here fits 100%.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: The posted duplicate has solutions for this for MySQL5.x and also MySQL 8+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try counting the numers of rows  with points >= at the points of playerid = 1

```
select count(*)  from (
  SELECT PLAYERID
      , SUM(POINTS) AS POINTS 
  FROM TABLE1 
  GROUP BY PLAYERID 
) T 
WHERE T.POINT >= (
  SELECT SUM(POINTS) 
  FROM TABLE1 
  WHERE PLAYERID = 1
)
```

Comment: Tks a lot for your time and expertise @scaisEdge! Works 100% - problem solved! :D